# angular - controllers returning lists with factory

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs

i am very new to angular.
what am i doing wrong please tell me.
i have a service that returns a custom list object  in c# MyService in function called SellingList.
Now my error is that data is undefined.  i just really want to get the html to generate the list... not sure how to go about it and this code is all really just guesses...

here is the code i have in my module js file:

```
sellingApp.controller('sellingListCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$location', 'breeze', 'sellingService',
    function sellingListCtrl($scope, $location, breeze, sellingService) {
        $scope.init = function () {
            sellingService.Sales().then(function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
        $scope.init();
    }
]);



sellingApp.factory('sellingService', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        Sales: Sales

    };
    function Sales() {
        console.log(breeze);
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/MyServices/SellingList',
            params: {}
        }).then(function (result) { return result.data; })
        .catch(function (s) { console.log(s); });
    }
}])


and here is my html code

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="sellingApp">
<head>

</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="sellingListCtrl">
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <colgroup span="7"></colgroup>

            <tbody>

                <tr>
                    <td ng-repeat="item in lists">
                        {{ item }}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you added the controller anywhere in the html ?

Comment: Please check [link](http://www.peterbe.com/plog/promises-with-$http)  Personally, I would revise your function Sales() to use deferred promisses.

Comment: @SambhavGore - i added it in ng-controller.  isn't that what you mean?

Comment: after googling a bit more, I changed code to 
sellingApp.controller('sellingListCtrl', function ($scope, demoFac) {
    demoFac.fetchUserDetails().success(function (response) {
        $scope.lists = response;
    });
});              and this       sellingApp.factory("demoFac", ['$http', function ($http) {
    var obj = {};

    obj.fetchUserDetails = function () {
        return $http.get('/MyServices/SellingList');
    }

    return obj;
}]);                    and now it works but new error is that ngRepeat:dupes
Duplicate Key in Repeater

Comment: For dupes issue add `track by $index` in your ng-repeat.

Comment: @SambhavGore -- how do i add track by $index in code like this :  item in lists track by $index?  I saw online examples that specified [0,0]....i don't want to specify anything....

Comment: ok, i fixed the dupes angular error.  now here is what i'm left with - the page renders fine...  but it returns system.generic.list  - not my data!